# No event is firing when placing a custom data bound control in DataRepeater control in Windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Custom events in a custom data bound control are not firing in DataRepeater control. When I debug it I found that the DataRepeater Control recreates the control using Activator.CreateInstance and Copies the Properties and Events. In my case copying events doesn't copy the custom events that I hooked in.

For example

```
public class MyClass : Control
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    protected virtual void OnMyEvent()
    {
        if(this.MyEvent != null)
        {
            this.MyEvent(this,EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    private int selectedIndex= -1;
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedIndex;
        }
        set
        {
        if(this.selectedIndex != value)
        {
            this.selectedIndex = value;
            this.OnMyEvent();
        }
    }
    }
    //
    // DataBinding stuff goes here
    //
}

public Form1()
{
    InitialiseComponent();

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.Add("one");

    this.dataRepeater1.DataSource = list; // One Repeater

    MyClass test = new Myclass();
    test.DataSource = GetDataTable();

    this.dataRepeater1.ItemTemplate.Controls.Add(test);

    test.MyEvent +=new EventHandler(test_MyEvent);

}

// This Event should fire when selected index of Datatable is changed and is firing when placed directly in the form and  not firing when place in DataRepeater control///////////////////////
private void test_MyEvent(object sender, EventArgss e)
{
    // This event is not fired///////////////////////
}

private DataTable GetDataTable()
{
    ..// Create a data Table and return
}
```

Any help Appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the below forums. It will helpful to you.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbpowerpacks/thread/b8b2bf93-46d5-406b-8947-c7b9ba02a771

Regards,
Lingaraj S.